# Ajuda com Vetor na Logica de programação

Tags: c

A ideia é que imprima de acordo com a condição, só que estou perdido na lógica, pois não tem como uma posição do vetor receber os dois valores.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    int N,X[1000],i,band=0;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for (i=0; i<N ;i++) {
        scanf("%d", &X[i]);
        if(X[i]== 3 && (X[i] == 5))
        {
            band++;
        }
    }

    if(band!=0)
        printf("Vetor certo");
    else
        printf("Vetor errado");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A condição certa seria **ou** (representada por `||`).

```
if (X[i]== 3 || X[i] == 5) {
    band++;
}
```

Ou seja, caso o valor de `X[i]` seja 3 **ou** seja 5, a condição será verdadeira.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que posso entender, você apenas confundiu os operadores lógicos "E" com o "OU"
Apenas algumas dicas de boas práticas, evite criar variaveis iniciando com letra maiscúla, e existe um modo de fazer esse exercicio sem definir um valor exato para o tamnho do vetor, caso queira é so avisar!

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    int X[1000];
    int i;
    int band=0;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for (i=0; i<N ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &X[i]);
        if(X[i]== 3 || (X[i] == 5))
        {
            band++;
        }
    }

    if(band!=0)
        printf("Vetor certo");
    else

        printf("Vetor errado");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O certo é com o operador lógico E msm, tipo Se o vetor tiver 3 e 5, ele printa "Vetor certo"...Obg pela dica man, se tiver pensando em alocação dinâmica, n posso usar ainda, mas vlw:)

Comment: Já resolvi glr...'-'

Answer (score -2):

Código:

```
if (X[i]== 3 || X[i] == 5) {
    band++;
}
```